# System.FormatException - Appeared after I've added a new class

Tags: c#, parsing, textbox

(I'm new to C#). After I've split-up my class (which included they GUI and the calculation of the code) in each of its parts. (One class the GUI, one the program itself), it shows evertime I press on the Button for the calculation: System.FormatException

Following is the first class

```
class Annuitätenrechner : Annuitätendarlehen
{
public void AnRechner() {
        int betrag;
        betrag = Convert.ToInt32(betrag2.Text);
        betrag = int.Parse(betrag2.Text);

        [Irrelevent stuff following...]
         }
 }
```

Second class

```
public partial class Annuitätendarlehen : Window
   {

    public Annuitätendarlehen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void berechnen2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var AnRe = new Annuitätenrechner();
        AnRe.AnRechner();
    }
```

Got no idea why it doesnt work <.<

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `Annuitätenrechner` in your button handler. I think `betrag2` is a `TextBox` member of that _new instance_, so its `Text` property will still be empty (it's not the `TextBox` of your `Annuitätendarlehen` instance!). An empty string cannot be parsed to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rene's comment makes great sense already.

I would like to add my 2 cents:

1) In case you want to break whenever an exception is thrown, you could take a look at [VS 2013 and before](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.120).aspx) or [enter link description here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/).

2) You can check the $exception virtual variable in watch window and check its "stack" or inner exceptions for more detail of the error. Looking into the detail of the exception and the error message always helps.

For the question itself, you could also took a look at [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)'s document and check when "FormatException" will be thrown.

According to the document, betrag2.Text was not a valid integer when the button was triggered.

Comment: I've got your idea how to solve this, thanks. But now I got the next problem: I have no idea how to fix it. Tried different things, nothing worked. 

I have to take the value of a TextBox from another class, could you tell me with which method it would work? Thank you forward

Comment: Sorry, the question you asked was a little vague. What usually could be done is to set the value of the textbox somewhere, but that will really depend on what the "another class" is.

Comment: I'm fine now :) Rene was right with his idea. Your Links helped me too.